# Browse Excel then View in Datagridview then save in MySQL using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

Good Day , I have a program that enables the user to browse an excel file after that the excel file will be displayed and open in the `datagridview` , So Far the browse and open is working properly however i cant save the values in the `datagridview` , i want to save it to the `MYSQL Workbench`

can someone help me thanks , Should i use separate buttons or just one button

Here is the Code : for Browse and Open Excel file:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection

        Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter

        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

and here is the code for import to database, However it doesn't save it is place in different buttons

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    For Each column As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Columns
            Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; username = root;password=rootpassword; database=bussiness_violation"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `bussiness_violation`.`tbl_recordbusiness` VALUES('@ACCTNO', '@PERMITNO', '@LAST_NAME', '@FIRST_NAME', '@MIDDLE_NAME', '@COMMNAME', '@COMMADDR ','@PLATENO ', '@STATCODE', '@FORYEAR', '@ORDATE', '@ORNO', '@SERIES', '@ISSUANCEDATE', '@EXPIRATIONDATE', '@TotalAmt')", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCTNO", column.Cells("ACCTNO").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PERMITNO", column.Cells("PERMITNO").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", column.Cells("LAST_NAME").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", column.Cells("FIRST_NAME").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MIDDLE_NAME", column.Cells("MIDDLE_NAME").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMMNAME", column.Cells("COMMNAME").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMMADDR", column.Cells("COMMADDR").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLATENO", column.Cells("PLATENO").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATCODE", column.Cells("STATCODE").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORYEAR", column.Cells("FORYEAR").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDATE", column.Cells("ORDATE").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORNO", column.Cells("ORNO").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERIES", column.Cells("SERIES").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISSUANCEDATE", column.Cells("ISSUANCEDATE").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRATIONDATE", column.Cells("EXPIRATIONDATE").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmt", column.Cells("TotalAmt").Value)


                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using


        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.")


End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the interface [Test GUI for Browse and Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbmtV.jpg)

Comment: You dont need any of that code.  Save the data in the DataTable to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get ? Is it a VB error or sql error ?

Remark : the code to save to the database is wrong, for each column, you instantiate a new MySqlConnection. Put this part above your for each

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "..."

For Each column As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Columns
    'Your code here
```

Comment: Here is the error An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in tester.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.

Comment: what line of code gives that error ? Is it when it loads the Excel file ? Or when you try to save it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what error you got.  I have updated your code to show the error message. Assuming its "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.XX.0 provider is not registered on the local machine" error." You need to update the Target CPU to x64 or x86 based on the installation on your system. see the [image].

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim isOpened As Boolean

    Try
        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            isOpened = True
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If isOpened Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```